# Query MongoDB, replacing one specific field with regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

If I have a collection defined as,

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
```

How can I query for all documents, but replace every password into asterisks?

Something like,

```
const users = await User.find({
  password: password.replace(/./gi, '*');
})
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this with `find()` query as it is only used to retrieve data instead can use [**`aggregate`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) for this with a [**`$addFields`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) stage.

```
const users = await User.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "password": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": { "$range": [0, { "$strLenCP": "$password" }] },
        "initialValue": "",
        "in": {
          "$concat": [
            "*",
            "$$value"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])

console.log({ users })
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wp-FvmJMqHp)

Comment: Is there a way to avoid hardcoding the asterisks and know exactly the length of password?

Comment: You want the asterisk as per password's length?

Comment: Yes, without sending a hardcoded value of `***********` to the front end.